# Free phishing email dataset examples

Tags: email, nlp, dataset, phishing

I am searching for phishing email datasets and could find only a couple of them till now. The are the Enron,  SpamAssassin, TREC 2007, UCI dataset, Nigerian Fraud Emails, Hilary Clinton Email Dataset,  Nazario and Lingspam. These are however seem to be old examples.

Do you know any current datasets that one can download and use for NLP?

Thanks in advance